# How can I associate each button in a set of video containers with its video?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out, how i can reproduce a single video when i have about 10 videos.

Every video has a "preview" button, and i'm trying at least to get the entire tag .

How the script should be written?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var test = $(this).parent().html();
        alert(test);
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<?php
foreach($dblines as $video_data) {
    list($number, $duration, $prize, $desc) = explode("|", $video_data); ?>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="wrap_img_vid">
    <video id="player" controls src="./preview/pre_<?= $number ?>.webm" poster="./preview/img_<?= $number ?>.jpg"></video>
    <span>N°<?= $number ?></span><span>Durata: <?= $duration?></span>
    <p><?= $desc ?></p>
    <button>Preview</button>
</div>
</div><?php } ?>

</div>
```

The jquery code is only for testing, because all my try has always failed. After many hours i decided to write here hoping in your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: jQuery questions should show the rendered markup on which it is acting, not server-side template code.

Comment: @isherwood Sorry, i haven't understand :(

Comment: I don't know what language or templating engine `<?=` is from, but jQuery never sees that. Instead, show the rendered markup as the browser displays it. It should contain only valid HTML. Then we can see the final structure and repeating elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in number of different ways.

You will first have to target the outer `div` (wrapper). In your code the `id` are not unqiue. You will run in to issues if you do not make the `id` unique.

However, you can completely get rid of id's and give a class and then access that. So, instead of this,

```
<div id="wrap_img_vid">
```

Change the element like this,

```
<div class="wrap_img_vid"></div>
```

And, then target that block and get to the button. This is the JS code to access the button click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('.wrap_img_vid button').click(function() {
          var vid = $(this).siblings("video")[0];          
          if(vid.paused) {
              vid.play(); 
          } else { 
            vid.pause(); 
          }
       });
  });
});
```

Here is a fiddle :- https://jsfiddle.net/anjanasilva/5pmckwns/

Since you are in a loop, you might need to wrap the `click` with a `setTimeout`.

To play the video, you will need to get to that element and trigger the `play()`. Something like this would do the trick,

```
$(this).siblings("video")[0].play();
```

To check if the video is `paused` before pressing the `play` button, you can do something like this,

```
var vid = $(this).siblings("video")[0];
vid.paused ? vid.play() : vid.pause();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works only for the first video, why?
I need to get `<video>` tag of each video to play

Comment: @ChristianWeb I have updated my answer. Can you have a look please?

Comment: Now its ok, but to play the video via "preview" button?

Comment: You will need to get the 'video' element and trigger the 'play()'. Check my answer again.

Comment: Sorry, i got this error: TypeError: $(...).closest(...).play is not a function

Comment: I think it was because of the `closest`. Use `siblings` instead. I have changed my answer. All you need to do is get to the `video` element.

Comment: I made a change to my code, it needs to be `$(this).siblings("video").trigger('play'); `. Check the fiddle too.

Comment: Cool. Glad you got your issue sorted.

Comment: Yes! It works now!
But with click again is possible to stop it? or pause it.

Comment: Yes, you can. I have updated my answer. If my answer is helpful could you please make my answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: `var vid = $(this).siblings('video');
vid.paused ? vid.trigger('play') : vid.trigger('pause');`
Nothing happen now :(

Comment: Please check my updated answer. It is `var vid = $(this).siblings("video")[0];
vid.paused ? vid.play() : vid.pause();`

Comment: vid.paused ? vid.play() : vid.pause(); <-- Now is good!!! Thanks a lot for your patience :) Have a nice day!